# Dynamically setting time of cron job based off of system variables

Tags: bash, automation, cron, environment-variables

I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically populate the time of a cron job off of an environment variable. For example:

`export JOB_MINUTES=4`

Then in the crontab

`$JOB_MINUTES * * * * /tmp/my_script.sh`

Resulting in a crontab of

`4 * * * * /tmp/my_script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables aren't expanded inside the crontab file. But you can use the environment variable when you're creating the crontab file, by piping an `echo` command to `crontab`.

```
{ crontab -l ; echo $JOB_MINUTES * * * * /tmp/my_script.sh; } | crontab -
```

The `-` filename argument means to get the crontab contents from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of @barmar's solution, but this one does an in-place substitution:

```
{ crontab -l | sed -E "s#^[^ ]* (.*/tmp/my_script.sh.*)#$JOB_MINUTES \1#"; } | crontab -
```

- just replaces the first token of the time spec
- assumes that the cron job has `/tmp/my_script.sh` in its command line (change to suit your requirement)

You may combine both the approaches into one:

```
if ! crontab -l | grep -q /tmp/my_script.sh; then
  # add to cron
  { crontab -l ; echo "$JOB_MINUTES * * * * /tmp/my_script.sh"; } | crontab -
else
  # update cron
  { crontab -l | sed -E "s#^[^ ]* (.*/tmp/my_script.sh.*)#$JOB_MINUTES \1#"; } | crontab -
fi
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run the command: `"-":25 bad minute`

Comment: I needed to escape the script and * characters

Comment: Good point.  I updated the answer and put the cron line inside double quotes.